# How to create image multimedia components using external URL using Tridion core service

Tags: core-service, cme, multimedia

I have an excel sheet which contains the column with External Image URL and i need to create the multimedia component using that URL and add this image component in my normal component, can anyone help on this with sample code.

Comment: Have you already tried this and come across problems? Or are you asking for more general help about how to get started? You are much more likely to get a good response if you improve your question by adding details of what you have tried and the problems you encountered.

Answer (score 7):

Here some sample code. I hope this helps.

```
CoreServiceClient channel = new CoreServiceClient();

ComponentData component = new ComponentData();
component.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
component.ComponentType = ComponentType.Multimedia;
component.BinaryContent = new BinaryContentData() {
    IsExternal = true,
    ExternalBinaryUri = "http://static.businessreviewonline.com/user/storefronts/cbr/tridion/tridion.gif",
    MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData() { IdRef = "tcm:0-1-65544" }
};
component.LocationInfo = new LocationInfo() { 
    OrganizationalItem = new LinkToOrganizationalItemData() {
        IdRef = "tcm:3-1004-2" 
    } 
};
component.Title = "Test External Image";
component.Schema = new LinkToSchemaData() {  IdRef = "tcm:3-8-8" };

channel.Save(component, null);
```

Comment: It's safer to use `GetDefaultData` method instead of setting ID and location manually